# VVOSC Connection Issues On Device (Works fine in simulator)

Tags: ios, macos, osc, max-msp-jitter

I'm writing an iOS app in which an iPad sends OSC messages, using the `VVOSC` libary, to a `Max/MSP` patcher, using the CNMAT `OpenSoundControl` object.

The iPad is sending messages to port `9000` at an IP address I've manually set for my laptop. The laptop creates a network, and the iPad is connected to it. The firewall is turned off.

That's my current setup! Now, when I test the app in the simulator, it works fine, and the OSC message is received by the patcher. However, when I run the app on the iPad, no message is received, and nothing shows up in the Mac's Console.

I'm probably missing something pretty obvious here, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending the OSC from your iPad to any other app than Max/MSP?

Comment: Yep, I tried sending it to a test python script running SimpleOSC, with no success there either.

Comment: In that case I guess we'd need more info about your code. Perhaps you're sending to localhost in your app? Did you try sending OSC from the simulator to another computer?